# Continuous probability density function question but x≥1

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, probability-distributions

If the probability density function for a particle to be at a particular location is given by f(x) = cg(x) for some constant c. And g(x) is:

g(x):= {(0, if x≤0), (x, if 0<x<1), (x^(-5/2), if 1≤x)}

Q1.) How would I find the value of the constant c?

Q2.) How would I find the mean (expected location of the particle)?

I'm trying to do question 1 but I don't know how to find c. I know I have to make 1 equal to the integral of both functions multiplied by c. I do the integral of x from 0 to 1 multiplied by c but I'm not sure what to do for the limits for the integral of x^(-5/2) as it is for x≥1?

And then once I found c what limits would I use to calculate the mean?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: $g$ is not integrable so there is no value of $c$ that makes $f$ a density function.

Comment: @LoganKay : kavi is telling you that there is an error in your exercise. Check g expression or its support. There is a typo somewhere. For example if you had $x^{-5/2}$ the problem was ok

Comment: @LoganKay : I have a crystal ball...actually it is really $x^{-5/2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral all over the support must be 1

You have

$$\int_0^1 x dx+\int_1^{\infty}x^{-\frac{5}{2}}dx=\frac{7}{6}$$

thus

$$f_X(x)=\frac{6}{7}x\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(x)+\frac{6}{7}x^{-\frac{5}{2}}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[1;\infty)}(x)$$

With mean

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx=\dots=2$$